# Create a blog post from content in another post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The Wordpress site I'm working on has a section for "News" (which is the regular blog/posts) which will be used for any news the company has to write about. Then I have a custom post type for Promotions, which has it's own page.

I want the client to be able to add his promotion content through the custom post type, which is going on the Promotions page, however I'd like this content to also be "cross posted" into the blog/news without forcing the client to write it up twice.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Just a note: The reason I have the promotions as a custom type on it's own instead of just having them do it all from the blog is because I needed custom fields that would be unnecessary for any other kind of blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

#### 1) Use the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

And in your cross-post you'd add the shortcode `[crosspost id="POST-ID"]`. Where `POST-ID` corresponds to the numeric ID of the other post (post type). Instead of ID, the title could be used, see the function [`get_page_by_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).

[Create your own plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/12615) for this. Add a sample shortcode from the Codex and use the function [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to get the contents of the cross-post.

#### 2) Use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin

With it, adding meta boxes with custom fields is a breeze. And it has a `Post Object` field that's basically a Cross Post functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a lot more simply by adding a filter to wp_insert_data(). For example, in your theme's functions.php file add the following:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'post_to_other', 99, 2);
```

That filter will then run anytime you add a new post. In the function post_to_other(), you look to see what type of post is being submitted. If it's a promotion, then insert a second copy as a News item.

```
function post_to_other($post_id, $post){

/** check $post to see what type it is, if it's a promotion */
if($post->post_type == 'promotion'){
$second_post = array(
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'post_title'=> $post->post_title,
            'post_name' =>$post->post_name,
            'post_content'=> $post->post_content,
            'post_author'=> $post->post_author,
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'tax_input'=> array('taxonomy_name'=>array('news'))
            );
            wp_insert_post($second_post);
}

}
```

I'm running out the door so I don't have time to double check the exact code but that's the basic structure of it. The tax_input bit is optional, lets you specify a category if you want. You'll probably need to tweak it a bit but that's the basics.

Comment: This is great, thank you! One question though, would I be able to take the post content and edit it slightly for the second post? Just as an example, the promotion has 2 items and a description for both (each it's own custom field)--would I be able to post just one description instead of the entire original post to the news item?

Comment: Haven't been on in a few days. Yes, you can edit the second post. In fact, if you're saving post meta you're going use update_post_meta (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). It will create a new meta field if one doesn't already exist, or update an existing one. So in the code above, right after wp_insert_post you would do whatever modifications you want to the post_meta. Also, just FYI, the above code won't handle post_meta fields. You'll need update_post_meta for that anyhow.